# Finding a regex to return all special characters in a single group

Tags: java, regex

I want the regex to return all special characters in a single group. I have made the regex that would return the characters using `[^a-zA_Z0-9]` but this one does not return the characters not being a letter or digit in a single group.

For example if the string to be checked is `Today is ~Friday()` then I am expecting that the output would be `~()` in one string so that I can replace them in one go.

But using the regex I provided I am getting:

```
0: [14,15] ~
0: [21,22] (
0: [22,23] )
```

Comment: Have you read about [repetitions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)? Try with  `[^a-zA_Z0-9]+`. Also asking for resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Consider removing this part from your post or your question will be closed. Anyway you should probably read also [Java official tutorial about regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: removed the resources

Answer (score 2):

Try using replaceAll method.

Below you have code that find all fragments matching to normal character sequence and replaces that sequence with empty string.

```
    String in = "Today is ~Friday()";
    String out = in.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", "");

    System.out.println(out);
```

And the result is:

```
~()
```